# "largest of any mammal" vs. "largest of all mammals"

Tags: phrases, expressions, comparatives

> A: This animal is the largest of any mammal.

vs.

> B: This animal is the largest of all mammals.

What are the subtle differences between A and B?

Comment: "largest of **any** mammal" is just wrong and doesn't make sense in the sentence.

Comment: @Kris No. There's nothing wrong with “largest of any mammal”. Your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @Kris - Janus is right. Google the phrase "largest of any", and you'll encounter plenty of similar constructions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. In sentence A, 'any' in effect means 'all', which makes sentences A and B equivalent in meaning.

Comment: One is plural and the other is singular. So I think they must have SUBTLE differences.

Comment: @xmllmx - That doesn't necessarily follow. With the construction you present in A, 'any' can only describe a singular noun; with the construction in B, 'all' can only describe a plural noun. But so what? What kind of subtle difference do you *think* there might be as a consequence?

Comment: +1 - @xmllmx - The construction of any is often used in informal contexts to mean "of all," as in *He is the best known of any living playwright.* (i.e. all.) No difference. Also, *any* can be plural. Check a dictionary.

Comment: @Kris, why the downvote? This answer is correct. Look up *any* in a dictionary or two, would you? Sheesh.